# Semantic UI popup with D3/SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, semantic-ui

I'm currently making charts with D3 and the UI Framework is Semantic UI. The problem I'm have is that I can't seem to get popups to work with SVG elements.

Like so:

```
            points.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "point")
            .attr("r", 3)
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.key) + x.bandwidth() / 2; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                if (d != undefined) {
                    if (d.value.ExcludedCount <= 0) {
                        return y(d.value.Average);
                    }
                    else if (d.value.Average <= (minVal - padding)) {
                        return (y(minVal - padding));
                    }
                    else if (d.value.Average >= (maxVal + padding)) {
                        return (y(maxVal + padding));
                    }
                    else {
                        return y(d.value.Average);
                    }
                }
            })
            .style('fill', function (d) {
                //return "grey";
                if (d.value.ExcludedCount >= d.value.data.length) {
                    return "grey";
                }
                else if (d.value.Failures <= 0) {
                    return PassFillScale(JSON.stringify(this.parentNode.__data__.ObjKey));
                    //return "#c6efce";
                }
                else {
                    return FailedFillScale(JSON.stringify(this.parentNode.__data__.ObjKey));
                    //return "#ffc7ce";
                }
            })
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                //return "black";
                if (d.value.ExcludedCount >= d.value.data.length) {
                    return "black";
                }
                else if (d.value.Failures <= 0) {
                    //return "#006100"
                    return PassBorderScale(JSON.stringify(this.parentNode.__data__.ObjKey));
                }
                else {
                    return FailedBorderScale(JSON.stringify(this.parentNode.__data__.ObjKey));
                    //return "#9c0006";
                }
            }).attr('data-tooltip', "Text Goes Here")
            .attr('data-position', "top left");
```

And I've tried binding the event these ways:

```
        $((".point")).popup({
            supports : "svg"
        });

        $(".point").popup();

        $(d3.selectAll(".point")).popup();
```

With no luck, have any of you run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Semantic-UI popup in a d3 viz in a Vue.js application. In order to get the popup to appear I had to change one character in the Semantic-UI CSS (v 2.3.1) script:

In `node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.js`, I had to change the operator in line 10869 from `===` to `!==`.  The working fragment, with context, is below:

```
10867    supports: {
10868      svg: function() {
10869        return (typeof SVGGraphicsElement !== 'undefined');
10870      }
10871    },
```

My event binding is a little different, as I add a handler for the d3 event in a Vue component `mounted` hook, inside the component which contains the `template` that contains the `svg` element within which the d3 event is triggered.  I'm convinced the `supports.svg` function is the issue here, and not the binding or handling approach.